# Need help with inverse laplace transform problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, laplace-transform

I'm really stuck this problem.

This actually resulted because of equations for a circuit analysis problem, so in case it would help I'll list the equations here too. Although, feel free to ignore them. We are solving for currents $i_1$ and $i_2$,

$$(i_1 - i_2)s - 2s^{-1} + i_1 = 0 \\ (i_2 - i_1)s + i_2 + (s^{-1} + i_2)2s^{-1} = 0 \tag{1}.$$

I get that $i_2$ is given by,

$$i_2 = {2(-s^3 + s + 1)\over s((s^2 - s - 1)s^2 - s(s + 1) - 2(s + 1))} \tag{2}$$

I am supposed to calculate the inverse transform of,

$$\displaystyle V(s) = (s^{-1} + i_2)2s^{-1} \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \  {2(s^3 - 3s^2 - 2s - 1) \over s(s^4 - s^3 - 2s^2 - 3s - 2)} \tag{3}$$

The expression for $V$ was obtained with sage. I can't see any easy way to decompose $V$, and this is where I am stuck.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: First, are you sure you wrote the systems equations properly and then solved them properly? I get different values for $i_1$ and $i_2$?

Comment: @Amzoti Yeah, that could be it. I got two different expressions for $i_2$ by solving the system differently. I guess I'll just have to try another approach.

Comment: Glad it all worked out and you are very welcome! Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the following results (you can plug these into $(1)$ and see if they satisfy each of the system's equations):

$$i_1 = \frac{2(s^2 + 2)}{s(2s^2 + 3s + 2)}$$

and

$$i_2 = \frac{2(s^2 - s - 1)}{s(2s^2 + 3s + 2)}$$

You gave:

$$\displaystyle V(s) = (s^{-1} + i_2)2s^{-1} = \left(\frac{1}{s} + \frac{2(s^2 - s - 1)}{s(2s^2 + 3s + 2)}\right)\frac{2}{s} = \frac{8s + 2}{s(2s^2 + 3s + 2)}$$

The Inverse Laplace Transform is given by:

$$ \displaystyle \mathcal{L}^{-1} (V(s)) = V(t) = 1-\frac{e^{-3 t/4} \left(\sqrt 7 \cos\left(\sqrt 7 t/4\right)-13 \sin(\sqrt 7 t/4)\right)}{\sqrt 7}$$

However, like I said, you had better validate my $i_1$ and $i_2$ since they do match yours.

**Update**

Note: I substitute $a = i_1$ and $b = i_2$ to get rid of any potential issues. Find a Wolfram Alpha solution to the simultaneous equation for $i_1$ and $i_2$.

Here is a [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%7B%28a+-+b%29s++-+2s%5E%28-1%29+%2B+a+%3D+0%2C+%28b+-+a%29s+%2B+b+%2B+%28s%5E%28-1%29+%2B+b%292s%5E%28-1%29+%3D+0%7D+for+a%2C+b) solution to the simultaneous equations.

Comment: Thanks for solving the system! Your solution seems to be on mark, also because of the type of circuit at hand; so I'll check and get back.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId: Please see the Wolfram Alpha link and solution to compare against what you are using. SAGE should certainly work! Regards

Comment: Ok, I double checked and I finally have the proper expressions for $i_2 \text{ and } V(s).$ Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Can you let us know if Ron was correct or if the above was correct or if it turned out to be another answer? Thanks

Comment: Well, Ron's was correct under the assumption that the expression for $V(s)$ in my op was correct, which it turns out it wasn't. You provided the correct expression for $i_2, V(s), \text{ and } \mathcal{L}^{-1}[V(s)].$

Comment: Great feedback to a very helpful answer! ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti I was looking at this problem again and realized that I have the incorrect inverse transform. I get that $v(t) = 1 - cos({\sqrt{7}t\over4})e^{{-3t\over4}} + {10\over \sqrt{7}}sin({\sqrt{7}t\over4})e^{{-3t\over4}}$. I decomposed $V(s)$ as $s^{-1} - {2s \over \alpha} + {5 \over \alpha} \ (\alpha = 2s^2 + 3s + 2)$, and went from there. Also, I factored $\alpha$ as $2\left(\left(s + {3 \over 4}\right)^2 + {7 \over 16}\right).$ What was your approach?

Comment: The expression I get is almost identical to yours; the only difference is that in my expression, the coefficient of the sine term is ${10 \over \sqrt{7}}$ rather than ${13 \over \sqrt{7}}$ as in yours. Also, using WA for the expression for $V(s)$ in my comment above gives me the same inverse as the one you have. But the problem is that I don't get the same expression doing the inverse manually.

Comment: I'll take it from $V(s) = s^{-1} - {2s \over \alpha} + {5 \over \alpha} = {1 \over s} - {s \over {\left(s + {3 \over 4}\right)^2 + {7 \over 16}}} + {4\over \sqrt{7}}{5 \over 2}{\sqrt{7}/4 \over {\left(s + {3 \over 4}\right)^2 + {7 \over 16}}}$. The expression has standard inverse transfroms; the inverse is $1$ for the first term, $-\cos\left({\sqrt{7} \over 4}t \right)e^{{-3 \over 4}t}$ for the second, and ${10 \over \sqrt{7}}\sin\left({\sqrt{7} \over 4}t \right)e^{{-3 \over 4}t}$ for the third.

Comment: You lost the 2 product in the middle term. When you fix that, you should get an inverse of -(e^(-3 t/4) (sqrt(7) cos((sqrt(7) t)/4)-3 sin((sqrt(7) t)/4)))/sqrt(7). When you add the sin term to the correct last term you got, you will get my result. Regards

Comment: Oh, I see! Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your expression for $V(s)$ is correct, there really isn't much you can do about the roots: the expression is not factorable over the rationals, or even square roots.  Rather, a plot reveals two real roots and a pair of complex roots; these you can find in terms of the horrifying quartic solution, or just numerically as I did.

Let the roots of the quartic be as follows:

$$s_1 \approx 2.45111 \quad s_2 \approx -0.788821 \quad s_{\pm} \approx -0.331144 \pm 0.931636$$

These are all simple roots, as is the root at $s_0=0$.  We may determine the ILT from the sum of the residues of the poles of the function $V(s) e^{s t}$.  The residue at $s_1$ is, for example:

$$2 \frac{2 s_1^3-3 s_1^2-2 s_1-1}{5 s_1^4-4 s_1^3-6 s_1^2-6 s_1-2} e^{s_1 t} \approx -0.26737 e^{2.45111 t}$$

where I used the fact that, for a simple pole $s_0$ of a function $p(s)/q(s)$ is $p(s_0)/q'(s_0)$  Repeat for all roots, and add; I get

$$f(t) = 1-0.26737 e^{2.45111 t}-1.22806 e^{-0.788821 t} + e^{-0.331144 t} [0.247714 \cos{0.961636 t} + 0.962263 \sin{0.961636 t} + i (-0.962263 \cos{0.961636 t} +0.247714 \sin{0.961636 t})] $$

Comment: First, thank you for going through the trouble of finding the roots and the expression for $f$. Although, it now seems that I really did obtain an incorrect expression for $i_2$, because $f$ is supposed to be capacitor voltage which, here, will eventually go to negative infinity. Uhhhh, back to the drawing board for me.